# DCFL substitution closure

Tags: formal-languages

Deterministic context-free languages are not in general closed under substitution. I have been looking at the DK-test (it is described in the 3rd edition of Sipser's Intro. to Theory of Computation, 2012) which can be used to check if a given CFG is deterministic, and it seems to me this can be used to show that DCFLs are closed under substitution when the substituted languages are disjoint DCFLs. Is this a known result? Or is anything known about the substitution closure of DCFLs with other restrictions on the substituted languages?

Answer (score 2):

Since $ab$ is a DCFL, your result would imply that DCFLs are closed under concatenation, which they aren't. So your result can't hold.

Comment: Thanks. Still, it would only imply closure given the concatenated languages are disjoint, right? (I do see that it still would not hold). Do you have any idea about substitution with end-marked DCFLs, or end-marked & disjoint DCFLs?

Comment: I'd guess that end-marked & disjoint alphabet should work. Disjoint languages with the same alphabet could get tricky, if the PDA can't decide early enough, which criteria it should test (cp. non-closure under union).

Comment: Doesn't having disjoint alphabets have the same effect as end-markers?

Comment: @sjmc Only if the word before substitution contains no substring $aa$ for any $a\in \Sigma$.